# Storing key value pairs in HTML to pass them to JS functions as variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that takes an object consisting of a number of key value pair as input. These objects can get rather long so I was wondering if I could store these objects as a variable some other place in the html document instead of writing them out again and again.

My initial idea was putting it in a div and hiding the div via IDs and inner.html. But that seems very sketchy, so I was wondering if there is a better way to go about that.

PS: No JQuery solutions please.

Comment: HTML really isn't the right place for this. Can't you load the data over AJAX from a server script or JSON file?

Comment: how do you store them at the moment?

Comment: Where do you get this data from? What speaks against simply storing it in a variable?

Comment: Why don't you put your data directly into a variable within the script tag?

Comment: There is no server, just a static HTML page that changes content when a button is pressed. Everything is stored in that page. ATM I pass the relevant object to an external function each time. It just occurred to me that there may be a way to save me from typing it each anew each time if I could define it as some sort of variable and refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an hidden div and place the code like this:

```
var obj={ 
      k1: 'v1',
      k2: 'v2',
      k3: 'v3'
}

<div> <script>JSON.stringify(obj);</script></div>
```

---

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Will output the follwing:

```
"{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2","k3":"v3"}"
```

You can store this string anywhere you like

Comment: If his only use case is to pass that data into a (JS) function, storing it as a string might not be that useful.

Comment: That does exactly the opposite of what I need. I want to input the string, store in HTML and pass it to an external JS function as input.